# How to remove a specific special character from a string along with all Alphabets

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have s string which looks something like

```
"USD $1,111.11"
```

Now i want this in the following format

> "1111.11"

In short i want the letters "USD" , Dollar sign "$", and the "," sign removed

So if i do `.replace('/^\D+/g','');` I get

"1,111.11"

And if i do `.replace('/\D+/g','');` I get

"111111"

So how can i modify my regex(I think the 1st one is a bit closer to my desired output) to give me my desired output.

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question?

Comment: Yes. I reframed it and asked again.

Comment: What does “all Alphabets” mean in the question title? Does it refer to É, г, я too (they’re alphabetic characters)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just ignore both the numbers and the dot, like this

```
console.log("USD $1,111.11".replace(/[^.\d]/g, ""));
# 1111.11
```

Comment: Actually, that Debuggex screenshot bothers me. "None of" sounds to me (as a non-native speaker I may be mistaken, though) that an empty string would fulfill that condition as well. I understand that "any character except [...]" wouldn't fit there, but still... (+1 anyway)

Comment: This may be what is *wanted* here, but it does not do what was *asked* (which is somewhat unclear but was formulated as removing some positively defined set of characters rather than removing everything except digits and periods).

Comment: @TimPietzcker You are correct, that might not be very appropriate here. I just removed it.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question how I would interpret it literally (without interpreting that all non-numeric characters should be removed):

```
> console.log("USD $1,111.11".replace(/[a-zA-Z,$]/g, ""));
< " 1111.11"
```

Comment: That's why I wrote that I interpreted the question literally: "In short i want the letters "USD" , Dollar sign "$", and the "," sign removed". There is no mention of #.